# Access node name in ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I am trying to retrieve the string=Gate from the following.

```
<SCNHitTestResult: 0x1c4016dc0 <0.167996,0.067400,-0.095000> | geometryIndex=0 node=<SCNNode: 0x1c43e1100 'test' pos(0.000000 0.000000 -0.100000) scale(0.010000 0.010000 0.010000) | geometry=<SCNText: 0x1c43e0e00 | 3 elements | string=Gate extrusionDepth=1.000>  | no child> bone=(null)>
```

MyCode to Access Geometry and is working fine is as

```
let hitResults: [SCNHitTestResult] = sceneView.hitTest(location, options: hitTestOptions)
if let hit = hitResults.first { 
   print(hit.node.geometry) 
}
```

> I already have tried this hit.node.geometry?.name but this returns nil

Answer (score 0):

I just have solved this problem

```
node.name = "test"
if(hit.node.name == "test") { // Do Something }
```